# Covering in Sigma-Rings

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E$ be a collection of subsets in a space $X$.  I would like to show that for all elements $A \in \sigma(E)$, the $\sigma$-ring generated by $E$, the exists a countable collection of subsets $E_i\in E$ such that $A \subset \cup_{i\ge1}E_i$.

I am trying to proceed by assuming, on the contrary, the existence of some $B\in\sigma(E)$ which is not covered by a countable union of such $E_i$, and showing the $\sigma(E)\setminus \{B\}$ is still a sigma ring containing $E$, but this isn't working.  Is there a better way to proceed?

Comment: define $\mathcal B$ as the collection of elements $A\in\sigma(\mathcal E)$ that have that property. Then $\mathcal E\subseteq \mathcal B$ so it is enough now to prove that $\mathcal B$ is a $\sigma$-ring. I wouldn't be surprised if that indeed is the case.

Comment: Can't you just define $B$ to be set of all subsets in $X$ that has the covering property (not like it matters)?

Comment: Yes. That is also a possibility as well.